# Can not create a Rails Resource using ZSH

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, zsh

I'm trying to create the following resource in a Rails application

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

However, when I run this command I get the following error

```
zsh: bad pattern: [:new,
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: I think what you want to type at the command line is more akin to this: `rails g resource sessions new create destroy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a command, that's an entry in a `routes.rb` file.

Edit the file instead of trying to run it from the command line; no more command line error.